# display the name of the image using onchange="readURL(this);"

Tags: javascript, php

`preventDefault()` and `onchange()` together will not display image file name what do i need to do for this to work? how can i get rid of `preventDefault()`?

```
jQuery("#btn-Preview-Image").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  renderContent();
  jQuery("#download").removeClass("disabled");
});


jQuery("#download").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return jQuery(this).hasClass("disabled");
});
```

this is input with `onchange()`:-

```
<input type="file"  name="file1" id="file1" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?  where is `readURL` function code?

Comment: Where is `readURL` defined? How is `javascript` at Question related to `<input type="file">` element? You should be able to get `this.files[0].name` within `readURL()` call.

Comment: xcalliber  check the answer once and let us know it helped or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to security reasons browsers doesn't allow to get selected file original path.

What else you can get is given in below example:-

```js
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
   console.dir(this.files[0]);
   console.dir(this.files[0].name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file"  name="file1" id="file1"/>
```